# Logging RDS table inserts into AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights, cloudwatch-alarms

I have a requirement to extract data from a third party RDS Oracle table whenever it is updated or inserted. I thought of creating a trigger in the third party DB and calling a Lambda function to extract data when an insert happens. The third party has refused to allow external overheads like triggers in their system for our purpose. Considering this, I am analyzing over utlizing Cloudwatch logs to watch for inserts without intervening their DB setup. When instance table is inserted/updated, can this info be logged in cloudwatch or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can configure your Amazon RDS for the Oracle DB instance to publish log data to a log group in Amazon CloudWatch Logs. With CloudWatch Logs, you can analyze the log data, and use CloudWatch to create alarms and view metrics.
Amazon RDS publishes each Oracle database log as a separate database stream in the log group. For example, if you configure the export function to include the audit log, audit data is stored in an audit log stream in the */aws/rds/instance/**my_instance/audit*** log group. RDS for Oracle supports the following logs:

- Alert log
- Trace log
- Audit log
- Listener log
- Oracle Management Agent log
  [image]

Ref:
[Publishing database logs to Amazon CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Procedural.UploadtoCloudWatch.html)

Comment: hi Arpit, okay thank you for this information. Will go through the link you provided as well. But these seem more like general instance metrics being logged. I hope you went through the specific ask of say, we have a data table named TableA in the instance. When this TableA has an insert, need to know of the same. Is this recorded under any of the categories you have provided? thanks.

Comment: I believe it should be captured with General Logs.

Comment: That is great, should do I think. I will check more on this, thank you.